# GameObjects Array align

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question I want to solve. I have an array of game objects, which I want to align each one to a constant distance. I can do this manually, but the problem is that on each object I gave an event. When I click on one of them, it changes its sprite. In some cases the sprite are smaller and then the distance increases between the front and rear objects. How to maintain this constant distance between each object, only on the x axis. Below is the event that changes the sprite, and I manually tried for each object to move it. Objects are arranged in a line.

```
 private void DetectBadWord(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && canClick)
    {
        int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(goodWordsSequence, target);

        if (badWordsToList.Contains(targetIndex))
        {
            Debug.Log("Good Click");
            Asked++;
            //sManager.Play(goodFXClip);
            if (sentence.index == 0 && targetIndex == 1)
            {
                Vector3 cPos = new Vector3(goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position.x + 0.1f, goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position.y);
                goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position = cPos;
            }
            if (sentence.index == 3 && (targetIndex == 2 || targetIndex == 4))
            {
                Vector3 cPos = new Vector3(goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position.x, goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position.y - 0.03f);
                goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position = cPos;
            }
            Instantiate(goodEffect, goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(1f, 0f);
            goodWordsSequence[targetIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = goodWords[targetIndex];
        } 
    }
}
```

[Example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97bxK.png)

I think it should in Update, check every distance, and if it changes to restring it or to increase it depending on the sprite.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice creating custom events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events) that trigger when the object gets clicked. Checking for it every update is not needed, since we get a trigger when we want the check to occur.
It would be best (I think) to create a C# object that has a reference to all the objects in the array, so that this class can order them whenever one of them launches their (custom) 'clicked-event'

Comment: I have edited the question, there is an image showing which distance I want to compute

Comment: The problem is that it calculates the distance from the middle of the object

Comment: But it has to be from the edges